# Jinja2 passing value inside value

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I am trying to pass a dynamic value to my dictionary in my jinja template which in turn is a value.
Code is as below:

```
"wan_link_info": [
{% for i in range(3) %}

{
    "dummy": "{{ xyz_Links.abc_{{ i }}.abc_link_type }}",
}
{% endfor %}
]
```

Here the dummy will have value like `xyz_Links.abc_0.abc_link_type`, `xyz_Links.abc_1.abc_link_type`, etc.

These text will return a value.
Example say:

```
{{xyz_Links.abc_0.abc_link_type}} = "Stackoverflow"
{{xyz_Links.abc_1.abc_link_type}} = "Facebook"
```

When I run the above code I get this error:

```
**"jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'"**
```

Comment: I was able to form the required text by using: {% set link_type = 'xyz_Links.abc_' + i|string + '.abc_link_type' %}. However when I pass link_type to "dummy" (i.e. "dummy":"{{ link_type  }}") it prints the same as text and does not fetch the value. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to fetch dict value. It can be implemented like this:

```
"wan_link_info": 
               [
                {% for instance in xyz_Links %}
                    {
                    "dummy": "{{ xyz_Links[instance].abc_link_type }}",
                    }
                {% endfor %}
                ]
```